# grouping sprites and moving them?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, grouping, sprite

i want to group my sprites that i call from an array, so that i can move them as a group. I was told to use cocosnode, but i'm pretty sure he meant ccnode. Here is my code so far:

```
    sprites1 = (CCSprite *)[c1array objectAtIndex:0];
    sprites2 = (CCSprite *)[c1array objectAtIndex:1];
    sprites3 = (CCSprite *)[c1array objectAtIndex:2];
    sprites4 = (CCSprite *)[c1array objectAtIndex:3];
    sprites5 = (CCSprite *)[c1array objectAtIndex:4];
    sprites6 = (CCSprite *)[c1array objectAtIndex:5];
    sprites7 = (CCSprite *)[c1array objectAtIndex:6];
    sprites8 = (CCSprite *)[c1array objectAtIndex:7];

    column1 = [CCNode node];
    [column1 addChild:sprites1];
    [column1 addChild:sprites2];
    [column1 addChild:sprites3];
    [column1 addChild:sprites4];
    column1.position = ccp(0,0);
    [self addChild:column1];

    column2 = [CCNode node];
    [column2 addChild:sprites5];
    [column2 addChild:sprites6];
    [column2 addChild:sprites7];
    [column2 addChild:sprites8];
    column2.position = ccp(30,0);
    [self addChild:column2];

//ccotouchmoved code
column1.anchorPoint = ccp(touchLocation.x,touchLocation.y);
if (CGRectContainsPoint(c1,touchLocation)) {
        touchLocation.x = column1.position.x;
        column1.position = ccp(touchLocation.x,touchLocation.y);
}
```

how do I make the ccnode move smoothly. It jumps up a lot but I want a smooth transition up and down.

> xxx
>
> xxx
>
> xxx

x are my sprites i am moving my x down and up as a whole column and need to be able to move my x as a whole row as well, and once it goes off the top of the screen i need it to reappear on the opposite side of the screen and vice versa same for left and right.

Comment: What's the error when it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the reason it's crashed is that one of Sprite5, Sprite6, Sprite7, Sprite8 in `nil`. And it's denied to add nil children to `CCNode`.

In touchBegan method:

```
CGPoint touchLocation = ...;
CGPoint referencePoint = ccpSub(touchLocation, myNode.position);
//keep reference point somewhere
```

in TouchMoved method:

```
CGPoint touchLocation = ...;
myNode.position = ccpSub(touchLocation, referencePoint);
```

Comment: @lins314159, @Andrew, don't worry i got it working forgot to add that sprite is equal to the object in array. Just need to sort out movement.

Comment: @Andrew, at the moment the ccnode position which is at the bottom when you click above the position, the touchlocation is equal to the y-calue of ccnode so it jumps but i want it so that when you click at that point the ccnode does not jump to that position.

Comment: @Danger: change the anchor point of your node to coincide with your finger. Or store the the initial deviation in some variable and use it when moving

Comment: @Andrew, i've tried that but it still has the same problem i'll edit my code to show what i have at the moment, could you provide an example as i might have misinterpreted.

Comment: @Andrew, i tried this but it did not work, still the same issue. what i was trying to do is get a scroll effect like when you drag up and down like a scroll bar on a webpage, but like on a webpage if you click above the scroll bar, the scroll bar jumps to that position. I get that problem when i'm clicking above the ccnode.position. i want it like this but this is to do with layers http://dk101.net/2010/11/30/implementing-page-scrolling-in-cocos2d/